# Нужно что-бы console.log выводил данные вне функции. Сейчас выводит только если внутри console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $status = $('.custom_paging');
var $slickElement = $('.one_screen_scroll');

$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
    var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
    $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
    console.log(i);
});
console.log(i);
```

Comment: Так дела не делаются. Зачем вам это?

Comment: Мне дальше нужно ее использовать.

Comment: $(window).scroll(function(){
      var wayToElement = $(".one_screen_scroll").offset().top;
      var fromTop= $(window).scrollTop();
      console.log(fromTop);

      var count = 1;

      if(((wayToElement - 200) < (fromTop + 200)) && (i < 5)) {

         alert('test1');

      }
      else{
        alert('test2');
      }
    });

Comment: в этом коде....

Comment: Обработчик событий выполняется асинхронно, когда-то в будущем, когда это самое событие возникнет. Соответственно, использовать `i` можно только после возникновения события, а никак не раньше.

Comment: За области видимости почитайте уже. Если переменная объявлена внутри функции, то и доступна она только внутри функции. Если нужно в функции её значение обновить, а после выхода из функции использовать, то вы хотя бы саму переменную объявите до функции.